# Laravel send email via SMTP fails on Azure, local environment works fine

Tags: php, laravel, azure, email, swiftmailer

I'm developing a Laravel application and I need to use different settings to send emails (so users can send a message with their own email). I've set that up and it is working fine right now-- however, only in localhost test environments. When I move to production server (Azure VM), I always get the same error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

Regardless of whatever port and encryption type I'm using.

This is what I'm doing in my custom Mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Repositories\Email;

class DemoEmail extends Mailable
{
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public $email;
  public $request;

  public function __construct()
  {

  }
  public function build(Email $email,Request $request)
  {

    $this->email = $email;
    $this->request= $request;
    $usrsettings = $this->email->settings();

    $conf = [
      'driver' => 'smtp',
      'host' => $usrsettings["Servidor"],
      'port' => $usrsettings["Puerto"],
      'from' => [
        'address' => $usrsettings["Direccion"],
        'name' => $usrsettings["Nombre"],
      ],
      'encryption' => $usrsettings["encrypt"],
      'username' => $usrsettings["Cuenta"],
      'password' => $usrsettings["Contraseña"],
    ];

    \Config::set('mail',$conf);

    if (isset($request['cc']) && $request['cc']!=null) $this->cc($request['cc']);
    if (isset($request['bcc']) && $request['bcc']!=null) $this->bcc($request['bcc']);

    return $this->from($conf["from"]["address"],$conf["from"]["name"])
                ->subject($request["subject"])
                ->view('emails.crm');
  }
}
```

This approach works on local environments (scenario 1: Xampp on Windows, scenario 2: homestead) but not on the Azure VM, which is production environment. I've tested the same 3 email settings, they all throw the same error in production and send emails correctly in test environment.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For security and potential misuse ports for these services are blocked on VM instances. You need to unblock them manually.

A better approach is to use an external service for dealing with email like SendGrid or MailGun, but that’s not mandatory.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We did consider that, however, we have a desktop application that, basically, does the same thing as an email client and that goes through without a hitch. I am wondering if maybe that blockage only happens from php or something like that =/

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this would be caused by your production server IP being blacklisted or requiring authentication in order to send mail.

I have just had a similar issue with a new server - in order to send mail with just an SPF record in place but without proper authentication an IP needs to become established and earn reputation.

I'm hoping that after a few months of sending mail with authentication across my sites I should be able to send without setting SMTP server, username and password every time.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, a coleague just did a test on a desktop application from that same server and it goes through without problem. So I can't imagine it has anything to do with IP being blacklisted =/
I am truly and totally lost.